# Discussion with my manager or CEO on higher studies

Tags: manager, conversation

I am a working person in India and I am preparing to get into a college for my higher studies. The college I want to get into has only regular classes (no option of online classes). I cannot quit my current job due to financial reasons. So the dilemma I am facing is how to get into the college without quitting my job.

One solution is that I have to talk to my manager or CEO to help me financially for 2 years (duration of my master's) so that I can complete it without quitting my job. The ideal case for me would be to attend college without working but getting some salary for 2 yrs and then repaying them once I finish my college. The other way would be to work for half a day and get salary for that half day during these 2 years.

Please suggest the best way to talk to my superiors about this issue so that I can convince them to help me.

Comment: No, I have not seen it.

Comment: There is a solution to your problem. Take courses at night. Adjust your working schedule to take the courses during the day. Work weekends to make up for the workdays your missing. Take the pay cut for the missing hours. Pay for the classes yourself but still ask for the time away. What the best way for you will be entirely dependent on your employers willingness to help you attend those classes

Comment: "repaying them once I finish my college." is giving out credit and accept repayment by company this way is legit within the country your company is located?  Wouldn't that be done by a credit institute instead?

Comment: @Ankit Seth, "The college I want to get into has only regular classes (no option of online classes)." Have you asked about their options for financial aid? Have you considered switching to a different College? One with online or night classes?

Answer (score 11):

You are making the same mistake that we see a lot of people make on this site when they want something in that all your arguments are based around *the value to you*, and makes no account whatsoever of the fact that your ideas will still be a significant cost to your employer: they will still have to hire someone to cover your role for two years, train that person - and then potentially lay them off after two years when you want your job back full time.

What you need to do is to come up with something which provides *mutual benefit* to both you and your employer; that will have to be sometime radically different from your current suggestions. Honestly, it seems the best option would be to find a different course which is more suited to your situation.

Comment: This is exactly the right answer. By the way, good lucky finding something of value that can outweigh the risk of the employee simply leaving the country once they have their degree.

Comment: The value to the employer is inherent - If I improve/expand my skill set, I will use those skills in my organization only. An organization's skills are simply the skills of its employees, so if employees improve their skills, it will directly contribute to the growth of the organization (my employer).

Answer (score 1):

You should approach this conversation by having to offer something of value to your employer. I have done this myself in the past and it is possible to work out, but it is certainly not easy.

Things to consider:

- Maybe your job and field of studies align and you can offer to do your masters project at work for the company. Check if there is a possibility to have a joint masters project with your university and workplace involved. It has a pitfall, that this project will probably be of more practical nature than it is suited for masters thesis so you will have to do some extra work to make the results more suitable for you thesis. But this is one good way to approach your goals.
- If that is financially possible to you, offer them to work at a lower rate. This will certainly make it more appealing to the employer.
- Be flexible at your workplace. There will times when you have more time from your studies and when you can do some more work for them.
- Take care of your health during all this. Balancing your studies and work is not easy and there is serious risk of burnout.
- Do not mention attending college and getting salary without doing any work. This is unreasonable.

Your employer might not be interested in you studying at all so you might have to look at other employment options.

Comment: Actually, the first point do apply to me. My job and the field of study align. In more than 95% of job postings, this degree is required. It is of quite a high value.